# Show post from specific category on the archive page

Tags: wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF and CPT UI to add my projects. Each projects post have a custom category assigned to it.

I am using this code below to display all projects in the archive page…

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'projets', 'paged' => $paged ) );
      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-4">
            <div class="box">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3> <?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            </div>
          </div> 

        <?php endwhile;
        if (  $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
          <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
          </div>

        <?php endif;
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

The code works well to get all the posts from all category but when I go to projects/category1, it still show all projects.

How can I modify this to show only the projects from specific category ?

Answer (score 1):

this is a good reference for WP_Query

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

This will show only post from a specific category

replace 'my_category_slug' with the category you are interested in.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'projets',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'category_name' => 'my_category_slug'
    ));

      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-4">
            <div class="box">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3> <?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            </div>
          </div> 

        <?php endwhile;
        if (  $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
          <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
          </div>

        <?php endif;
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

This though is usually not required have you refreshed your permalinks after creating the new post type. ie. go to settings permalinks and click save.

The standard loop should work for custom post types.

'''

```
<?php if(have_posts()): ?>

  <?php while(have_posts()): the_post() ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

'''

This would be your standard page layout to show the content then you would navigate to the the custom post type using http://yoursite.com/projets/

Though the loop above should already be included in your theme so you should rarely need to rewrite it unless building a theme from scratch.

Comment: Great! Since I have 10 different post categories, do you recommend creating 10 different templates ? Since this might be a little overkill, do you think we could customize the function to show the current category post based on the current category slug ?

Comment: if you need 10 of these then its not the correct way. usually the default way would show whatever category correctly for standard posts and even for custom post types. What theme are you using, is it bespoke made, paid for or one of the included ones with wordpress?

Comment: I am building a custom theme. The standard loop does show all projects here: http://yoursite.com/projets/ but nothing show up in http://yoursite.com/category/project-category-1

Comment: I found the issue, i had to activates post types ion category function themeprefix_show_cpt_archives( $query ) {
 if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
 $query->set( 'post_type', array(
 'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'projets'
 ));
 return $query;
 }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'themeprefix_show_cpt_archives' );

Answer (score 0):

have you tried WP default loop without any custom WP_Query i.e.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

because WP automatically determines which category projects post you're trying to view and show the projects post accordingly. 

Right now you're mentioning the "'post_type' => 'projets'" so due to that it's showing all the projects.

so please use WP default loop then view the category i.e.
sitename.com/CPT_taxonomy/category_name

then it'll only show the project related to that category only.
```

Comment: it does not work